# How do you breed a green sheep in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, I want to breed a green sheep. What colours do the parents have to be to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

Two green sheep will make another green sheep, or one blue and one yellow.

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep#Breeding):

> If the parents have 'compatible' wool colours (meaning that the corresponding dye items could be combined into a third dye colour), the resulting lamb will be a mix of their colours (e.g., blue sheep + white sheep = light blue lamb).

Additionally, using a dye on the sheep itself will permanently change the colour of the sheep's wool.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, blue and yellow will not make a green sheep. The best way to get a green sheep is to cook cactus in a furnace. Take the dye from the cooking process and color a sheep.

Comment: Of course, the wiki I used may have been out of date, so not 100% sure. I don't have a blue and yellow sheep right now to test. But, I did get a green sheep from cooking the cactus.

Comment: might be a good idea to link to what wiki you are talking about. when i see *"according to the wiki"* with no link i assume [The Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki)

Comment: Thanks...
https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Dye

Snippet from the page...
Note that the color combining follows the same rules that dyes use – red and yellow sheep will produce an orange lamb, but a blue and yellow sheep cannot create a green lamb.